# Where to put sql files in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, directory-structure

Our Symfony2 project has many custom SQL files and queries which are used for manual database tasks (e.g. generating reports, debugging, development database setup, migrations etc.).
They usually correspond to separate versions of the source code and should be maintained within the same repository of the VCS.

Just to be clear, this is SQL that needs to be run exclusively manually.

*More context: Similarly, there are some bash scripts laying around which would probably share the same parent folder as the SqlFiles folder.*

Where should such documents be placed in the directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

`bin/` directory contains executable files, so put your shell scripts there.

`app/` is a directory for everything that is not PHP code. So I would put SQL files in either `app/sql/` or `app/Resources/sql/` directory.

If you use Doctrine, then I recommend [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) for database migrations. It can generate them automatically.